# Simply requiring a library in my Node.js app on Azure causes 500 internal server errors

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm brand new to Node.js and Azure development so I'm likely doing something silly.

I've created a brand new Node.js website app in Azure. When I upload the following code, it works:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json({ test: "test" });
});

app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

But as soon as I add this line at the top:

```
var sql = require("mssql");
```

I start receiving 500 Internal Server Errors. The Azure logs show:

> Fri Jun 23 2017 09:57:43 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time):
>   Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
>   **SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode**.
>       at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)
>       at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
>       at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
>       at require (module.js:375:17)
>       at Object. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mssql\index.js:1:80)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
>       at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:353:31)

The code doesn't throw errors locally.

I've done some googling and the only thing I can find is that this might be a problem with older versions of Node.js. I've tried adding that the node version to use should be greater than 6.0.0 in the packages.json, but this doesn't appear to do anything.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you are receiving is that you cannot use: 
`var sql = require("mssql");` 
but 
`const sql = require("mssql");`

It's because you are using `'strict mode';`. At the top of files, in javascript, you use `'use strict';`

To learn more about ''use strict';` you can read here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Comment: Hi Rafael - I've not specified 'strict mode' anywhere myself. The code I've posted is literally all the code there is.

Comment: My guess is that azure uses `'strict mode';` by default. To make your code work you won't be able to use ``var`` to declare variables, but `'let'` or `'const'`. Use `'const'` for constant variables (like requiring modules) and `'let'` for variables that can change throw the execution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Why would 'var' work for the express require but not for the mssql require?

Comment: You got me there. I don't actually know, but I would try using `'const'` and see if It works. By the way, I would not recommend using `'var`' over `'const'` for performance reasons.

Comment: That seems to have done it. Changing 'var' to 'const' made this work. I'm not sure why only mssql needed 'const' and express was happy with 'var'! Thanks a lot for your help, dude!